# What is the fastest method to calculate substring

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I have a huge "binary" string, like: **1110** 0010 **1000** 1111 **0000** 1100 **1010** 0111....

It's length is 0 modulo 4, and may reach 500,000.

I have also a corresponding array: {**14**, 2, **8**, 15, **0**, 12, **10**, 7, ...}

(every number in the array corresponds to 4 bits in the string)

Given this string, this array, and a number `N`, I need to calculate the following substring `string.substr(4*N, 4)`, i.e.:

for `N=0` the result should be `1110`

for `N=1` the result should be `0010`

I need to perform this task many many times, and my question is what would be the fastest method to calculate this substring ?

One method is to calculate the substring straight forward: `string.substr(4*N, 4)`. I'm afraid this one is not efficient for such huge strings.

Another method is to use `array[N].toString(2)` and then wrap the result with zeros if needed. I'm not sure how fast is this.

May be you have any other ideas ?

Comment: I don't know where you got the notion that substr wasn't fast. I'm not sure of your requirements, but in a simple test I made a string of 500,000 characters and then made a random sub-selection from it 100,000 times in about 169ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does the string come from?  Why not represent the string not as binary, but as hex, and then you can store each four-binary-digit section as a single character?  (You could obviously pack it twice that densely if you wanted, or actually now that I think of it, 4 times, since Javascript strings are 16-bit Unicode). Then finding a single group would be a single call to "charAt()", and you'd just have to expand to the binary form via a lookup table.

**edit** — oh well duhh, you already have an array. In that case don't do the substring work at all; it's crazy. Just grab the array element and translate it through a lookup array into the 4-binary-digit string.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider representing your huge string as a [Rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29) data structure. A rope is basically a binary tree whose leaves are arrays of characters. A node in the tree has a left child and a right child, the left child being the first part of the string, while the right child the final part.

By using a rope, substring operations become logarithmic in complexity, rather then linear, as they are for regular strings.

Comment: If he's going to split up the string like that, why not just split it up into a flat array? Then his lookups are **constant time** and not even logarithmic.

Comment: @Pointy Had he an array, and not a string, that would work. But splitting the string into an array still requires calling substring to get the individual sections.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it padded, you could do this:

```
var elem = array[N]
var str = "" + ((elem>>3)&1) + ((elem>>2)&1) + ((elem>>1)&1) + (elem&1);
```

Comment: ?? He said he's got a *string*, not an array. Your code assumes an array of numbers. Also, you get the binary strings backwards.

Comment: `I have also a corresponding array ...`. Good point about the direction of the bits though.

Comment: @Josh no, in Javascript they're not exactly arrays. They don't have the methods that arrays have.

Comment: However, the OP said he has an array as well as a string.

Comment: @Pointy True, but I don't see how that is relevant to the concerns of the OP

Comment: It isn't, but someday somebody else may be reading this page!

Answer (score 1):

The array already has exactly what you need, does it not, save that you need to print it in binary format.  Fortunately, [`sprintf` for javascript](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/sprintf-for-javascript) is available.